# C# WP8 Getting page URL adress with parameter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

I am trying to get a parameter from the URL but I am getting an error.
Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string str = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("data", out str))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("k");
        }
    }


private void aktualizuj(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var btndate = sender as DatePicker;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("dieta.xaml?data=" + btndate.Value.Value.Date.ToString(),UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, looks like your debugger is getting quirky.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("dieta.xaml?data=" +
    btndate.Value.Value.Date.ToString(),UriKind.Relative));
```

Should throw the exception:

`Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.    Parameter name: uri`

So you should change it to

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/dieta.xaml?data=" +
    btndate.Value.Value.Date.ToString(),UriKind.Relative));
```

If you're going to use `UriKind.Relative`